# Не могу понять в чем проблема Pytorch RNN

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, pytorch

Делаю **RNN** модель по предсказанию следующего слова.
Модель обучается нормально (судя по Loss), но предсказывает какой-то бред.
(Пример: "Люди крайне социальные животные, которым (тут уже предсказывает NN) и и и и и и и и и и и и и и и и и и и и" )

В чем моя ошибка?

Код (Google Colab): https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UyS00rWL8TdhvcIX19MaUrBfPrBbKwls?usp=sharing